# Image doesn't fit in parent div inspite of using .img-fluid class

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So, I've this little piece of test code where I'm trying to fit an image into the parent div as below in BS5. The challenge is that the image leaves a sizeable gap width-wise. This inspite of using `.img-fluid` class. Outcome attached which isn't ideal. There's a big gap. [image]

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Google Font -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">

    <title>Practice </title>
</head>

<body>

    <section class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row g-0 h-50 border border-2 border-success ">
            <div class="col-6 px-0"></div>
            <div class="col-6 px-0">
                <img src="image-header-desktop.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            </div>


        </div>




    </section>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is the image leaving a gap of half a page by any chance? I ask because it is housed in a column which is 6 wide. In Bootstrap language that's half a page horizontally. You could add `mx0auto` after `img-fluid` to center everything. Your img-fluid will only go to the width of it's parent column.

Comment: @CuteCodeRob But that's what's not happening. The second column is 6 wide. The width of the image is not covering all of it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not write an inline css.

```
<img src="image-header-desktop.jpg" alt="" style="width: 100%">
```

Comment: CSS shouldn't be required. The image is already 100% of it's parent Div using `img-fluid` but the Div is only half a page wide using `col-6`. 6 of 12 in Bootstrap.

Comment: @KingsleyUchenna actually using css works. What I don't understand is why do I need to do this inspite of using the .img-fluid class. The whole point of adding the class is to make width 100% of the parent element.

Comment: @PradyutVatsa I don't know, maybe there is an issue with bootstrap. I had issues with img-responsive it does not do any work when I use. So I had to create my own style.

You should just maybe in your custom styling or in the head tag create your own class with .img-fluid name and style it with 100% width.

Comment: It's a good question Pradyut. You're right. With Bootstrap you should not need to add your own styling for widths, margins and general spacing.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `col-6` that has the image inside it... It's making the thing appear just on the left side of the page?? This should work...

```
<div class="col-6 mx-auto px-0">
   <img src="image-header-desktop.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
</div>
```

Tha above only takes your normal thing and centers it on the page, I only added `mx-auto` to center the Div which contains your image.

You could also try `col-8` `col-9` `col-10` to make the image bigger. It will still be fluid and extend the full width no matter how many columns wide you are. Naturally you wouldn't want it fluidly expanding larger than it's normal pixel size though.

Comment: Nothing is happening by using mx-auto. All i'm trying to achieve is for the image to take the entire parent div i.e. 6 wide column in which it's housed. It's leaving a gap on the right.

Comment: I see that you have now posted an example. Thanks for doing that. Yes it is a strange error. Are you sure you have no other CSS that is applying a right margin or padding to images?